# How to install Python 3.6.0 in a VirtualEnv? instead of 3.9 (CLOSE ME)

Tags: python, virtualenv

When I updated the virtualenv on my computer (OS/X Big Sur), somehow Python version 3.9.0 was installed.  But my host environment continues to use 3.6.0 and I'd like to revert my development sdenv to that.  How is this done, please?

(To clarify: the `python3` command on my machine is 3.9.)

--- *I've decided to self-close this question as being probably-irrelevant to my actual concern, which is in another simultaneously-active SE thread concerning the "mysqlclient=1.4.3" package. This is probably a red herring.*

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to use some version manager for example I use

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

which allows me to switch between different python versions and thus create my virtual env with version that I want

Comment: It looks to me like it requires a particular python version to *also* be installed, so that its "shims" can select the right one.  I think that what happened here is that the upgrade in MacOS version changed the `python3` executable from 3.6 to 3.9.  Now, the true **reason** why I am interested in this is because of the other problem that I recently posted – an error in the `mysqlclient` package reinstall which is now failing.

Comment: I see but isn't still possible to use pyenv to bring back 3.6 for example ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason for the version-change is that some upgrade to OS/X probably changed the `python3` command executable, from 3.6 to 3.9.  The `venv` command apparently simply grabs whatever's there at the time.

My actual reason for posting this question has to do with a `mysqlclient=1.4.3` install which is now mysteriously failing.  And so, *this* issue might actually be a "red herring" to that fundamental question.  So, I think I'll just "table" this question now and focus on why that install is no longer working.  Possibly it doesn't actually have anything to do with 3.6 *vs.* 3.9.

Thanks for the quick responses, nonetheless.

P.S.:  And, hey, I even found my own answer to that question!